# Thread crash, which one is it?

Tags: iphone, crash, nsthread

My app crashes when it switches threads. Could not see which one is crashing? Anyone can see it from these details?

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

I tried to find the thread based on the hex 0x207, but there is no such thread.

```
    *** Mongoose debug *** get_socket: thread 0xb05ee000: going idle
[Switching to process 17284 thread 0x207]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x92067afa in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x92068267 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x0152d13a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x01490580 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x0148fdb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x0148fccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x01d71879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#7  0x01d7193e in GSEventRun ()
#8  0x00421a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#9  0x00001fda in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffebf8) at /Users/Zsolt/Documents/iPhoneDevelopment/Apps/oDesk/TPP/brians_tpp/HD Learning/HD Learning/main.m:16
#10 0x00001f25 in start ()
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 15 (process 17284):
#0  0x92095aa2 in __semwait_signal ()
#1  0x9209575e in _pthread_cond_wait ()
#2  0x920952b1 in pthread_cond_timedwait$UNIX2003 ()
#3  0x0002ec2a in get_socket (ctx=0x7070600, sp=0xb05edf30) at /Users/Zsolt/Documents/iPhoneDevelopment/Apps/oDesk/TPP/brians_wapp/tppLib/tppLib/LibCode/HttpServer/mongoose.m:4652
#4  0x0002e7e0 in worker_thread (ctx=0x7070600) at /Users/Zsolt/Documents/iPhoneDevelopment/Apps/oDesk/TPP/brians_wapp/tppLib/tppLib/LibCode/HttpServer/mongoose.m:4693
#5  0x92095259 in _pthread_start ()
#6  0x920950de in thread_start ()

Thread 14 (process 17284):
#0  0x92067afa in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x92068267 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x0152d13a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x01490605 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x0148fdb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x0148fccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x03327f90 in WebCore::runLoaderThread ()

Thread 13 (process 17284):
#0  0x9208d412 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x9208d9a8 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#2  0x9208d5c6 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 12 (process 17284):
#0  0x9208d412 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x9208d9a8 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#2  0x9208d5c6 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 11 (process 17284):
#0  0x9208d412 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x9208d9a8 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#2  0x9208d5c6 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 10 (process 17284):
#0  0x92086ac6 in select$DARWIN_EXTSN ()
#1  0x014c17fb in __CFSocketManager ()
#2  0x92095259 in _pthread_start ()
#3  0x920950de in thread_start ()

Thread 9 (process 17284):
#0  0x92067afa in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x92068267 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x0152d13a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x01490605 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x0148fdb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x0148fccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x00e13e40 in +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] ()
#7  0x00d254e6 in -[NSThread main] ()
#8  0x00d25457 in __NSThread__main__ ()
#9  0x92095259 in _pthread_start ()
#10 0x920950de in thread_start ()

Thread 8 (process 17284):
#0  0x92067afa in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x92068267 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x0152d13a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x01490605 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x0148fdb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x01491eb1 in CFRunLoopRun ()
#6  0x00064af2 in +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (self=0x9bd2c, _cmd=0x7da8a) at /Users/Zsolt/Documents/iPhoneDevelopment/Apps/oDesk/TPP/brians_wapp/tppLib/tppLib/LibCode/ASI/ASIHTTPRequest.m:4790
#7  0x00d254e6 in -[NSThread main] ()
#8  0x00d25457 in __NSThread__main__ ()
#9  0x92095259 in _pthread_start ()
#10 0x920950de in thread_start ()

Thread 7 (process 17284):
#0  0x9208d412 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x9208d9a8 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#2  0x9208d5c6 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 6 (process 17284):
#0  0x92086ac6 in select$DARWIN_EXTSN ()
#1  0x0002dd52 in master_thread (ctx=0x7070600) at /Users/Zsolt/Documents/iPhoneDevelopment/Apps/oDesk/TPP/brians_wapp/tppLib/tppLib/LibCode/HttpServer/mongoose.m:4805
#2  0x92095259 in _pthread_start ()
#3  0x920950de in thread_start ()

Thread 5 (process 17284):
#0  0x92067afa in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x92068267 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x001089ce in _LSPluginClient_GetStore ()
#3  0x0010c4cf in _LSCopyServerStore ()
#4  0x000fd614 in _LSContextInit ()
#5  0x00119feb in UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass ()
#6  0x02f5ed43 in WebCore::MIMETypeForImageSourceType ()
#7  0x03356f4e in WebCore::initializeMIMETypeRegistry ()
#8  0x03357bc0 in WebCore::MIMETypeRegistry::isSupportedNonImageMIMEType ()
#9  0x0332f609 in WebCore::shouldUseQuickLookForMIMEType ()
#10 0x036120a8 in WebCore::adjustMIMETypeIfNecessary ()
#11 0x034b980e in WebCore::didReceiveResponse ()
#12 0x001a3a07 in URLConnectionClient::_clientSendDidReceiveResponse ()
#13 0x00271764 in URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload ()
#14 0x002718b5 in URLConnectionClient::ClientConnectionEventQueue::processAllEventsAndConsumePayload ()
#15 0x0019b298 in URLConnectionClient::processEvents ()
#16 0x0027116b in non-virtual thunk to URLConnectionInstanceData::multiplexerClientPerform() ()
#17 0x0019b137 in MultiplexerSource::perform ()
#18 0x0152d97f in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#19 0x01490b73 in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#20 0x01490454 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#21 0x0148fdb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#22 0x0148fccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#23 0x03610220 in RunWebThread ()
#24 0x92095259 in _pthread_start ()
#25 0x920950de in thread_start ()

Thread 2 (process 17284):
#0  0x9208e382 in kevent ()
#1  0x018cd373 in _dispatch_mgr_invoke ()
#2  0x018cbcd0 in _dispatch_mgr_thread ()

Thread 1 (process 17284):
#0  0x92067afa in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x92068267 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x0152d13a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x01490580 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x0148fdb4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x0148fccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x01d71879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#7  0x01d7193e in GSEventRun ()
#8  0x00421a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#9  0x00001fda in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffebf8) at /Users/Zsolt/Documents/iPhoneDevelopment/Apps/oDesk/TPP/brians_tpp/HD Learning/HD Learning/main.m:16
#10 0x00001f25 in start ()
(gdb)
```